# d3 v4 scaleTime not accepting date object nor integer

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am implementing a step-after interpolation graph in d3 v4.
Times are saved as a string formatted as "hh:mm:ss.ss". I am passing the timeScale a range of integers by converting the time strings to seconds. Nonetheless I'm receiving "Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…"."

```js
function render(data) {
  const margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50};
  width -= margin.left + margin.right;
  height -= margin.top + margin.bottom;

  const bboList = data.bboList;
  bboList.push( bboList[bboList.length - 1] );

  const timeStrToDate = (timeStr) => {
    var time = timeStr.split(':');
    let d = new Date();
    d.setHours  (+time[0]);
    d.setMinutes( time[1]);
    d.setSeconds( time[2]);
    return d;
  }

  bboList.forEach(function(bbo) {
    bbo.time = timeStringToSeconds(bbo.timeStr);
    bbo.ask = +bbo.ask;
    bbo.bid = +bbo.bid;
  });

  function timeStringToSeconds(timeString){
    const hms = timeString.split(':');
    return (+hms[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+hms[1]) * 60 + (+hms[2]);
  }

  const minTime = timeStringToSeconds(bboList[0].timeStr);
  const maxTime = timeStringToSeconds(bboList[bboList.length - 1].timeStr);


  let xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(bbo) { return bbo.time; }))
    .range([minTime, maxTime]);

  const yExtent = d3.extent(data, function(bbo) { return bbo.bid; });

  let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(yExtent)
    .range([height, 0]);

  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale);

  const yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale);


  chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Price ($)");


  const line = d3.line()
    .x(function(bbo) {
      return xScale(bbo.time);
     })
    .y(function(bbo) {
       return yScale(bbo.bid);
     });

  chart.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line(bboList));

}
```

When I follow through the code with a debugger it seems that at every step I am returning either numbers or a bbo object made of numbers. I believe the issue is with my xScale but I'm not sure exactly what I'm looking for. Any guidance on how I should go about debugging this code, or finding a good resource for d3 v4 would be greatly appreciated (the documentation for .line is unclear to me)

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with your calls to `d3.extent`.

It seems you want to pass `bboList` to them, not `data`. [`d3.extent`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#extent) takes an array for its first parameter, whereas `data` appears to be an object of some description.

The scaling functions `xScale` and `yScale` don't do anything more than convert a value in the input domain into one in the output range.  One way to debug your code is therefore to try calling these scaling functions with some values and seeing what comes out of them, using, for example, `console.log(xScale(12345));`.  I tried playing with them and found that `NaN` values came out of them.

Comment: Thank you! You are absolutely correct that the issue was d3.extent. I still have some issues to resolve but this was a major road-block for me and I really appreciate your help.